# Record in a log what Python script did

Tags: python, logging

I have the following line code in a Python script:

```
sql_create_table(total_stores, "total_stores")
```

This is a function I created to upload tables to an Oracle database. I want to do something like this in order to record what tables were not created because the line failed to run:

```
Try:
    sql_create_table(total_stores, "total_stores")
except:
    print in a log.txt "table x could not be created in the database"
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write the log to a txt file by doing the following:

```
Try:
    sql_create_table(total_stores, "total_stores")
except:
    with open('log.txt', 'a') as log:
        log.write("table x could not be created in the database")
```

Note, that by using `'a'`, we are appending to the txt file and won't be overwriting old logs.

Answer (score 4):

There is the [python logging module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html), which has [a good tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#logging-basic-tutorial), which even includes how to [log to a file](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#logging-to-a-file).

Very basic example:

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(filename="program.log", level=logging.INFO)
…
try:
    sql_create_table(total_stores, "total_stores")
except:
    logging.warning("table x could not be created in the database")
```